# How do I assign an ID to an item in a DropDownList?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu

i want when i click on `drowpdownlist` take effect to it's rows for example `slidetogle`.
but problem is that the `html` code that it generates have no id like this:

```
<select name="DropDownList1" id="DropDownList1">
    <option value="123">Java++</option>

</select>
```

`dropdownlist` has a id but the `<option>` has not any id. how can i assign id to it or take effect to option that is for this `dropdownlist`?

Answer (score 3):

You can select all the `<option>`s inside your `<select>` using a descendant selector:

```
$("#DropDownList1 option").remove(); // No more options!
```

and you can do whatever you want with them. If you need a specific one by value, you can use an attribute selector:

```
$('#DropDownList1 option[value="123"]')
```

or, if you need one by index:

```
$("#DropDownList1 option").eq(index)
```

Comment: Or `$("#DropDownList1 option:eq(index)")`.

Comment: @Purmou: Yeah, I thought about that but if the index is dynamic it would become `$("#DropDownList1 option:eq(" + index + ")")`... not as pretty.

Comment: @minitech no they are not! http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/ . `Value An attribute value. Quotes are mandatory.`

Comment: @minitech: Good point, but worth noting that there *are* other options. Up to the OP if he wants pretty code or not. :P

Comment: @PeeHaa: I did the same thing on another answer--that's more for multi-word attribute values.

Comment: @PeeHaa: I'm well aware, I said that I accused somebody of not using the quotes either. But it works, doesn't it? There are a lot of things that are debatable in the jQuery docs--the authors are only human.

Comment: @Purmou The fact that it works doesn't mean you should do it. You mean they added that text by accident in the docs. Don't think so... Well just don't do it than and don't try to learn the correct way. It's almost 12 o clock here and I'm going to drink. Do with this information what you like... Cya in the new year.

Comment: @Purmou It is better you don't know or I'll have to kill you.

Comment: The quote requirement is not enforced because of legacy code. Just like in PHP where `abc === 'abc'` with `abc` not being defined as a constant (and it throws a notice) - even though that should really be removed no matter if it breaks old code or not.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Or possibly to maintain compatibility with [CSS2 selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#attribute-selectors). It would be silly to require quotes because `document.querySelector` supports quoteless selectors.